# I am using Spring boot jpa with Restful api services to insert multiple users in array or list

Tags: spring-boot, api, jpa

As I am new to Spring boot. I am not at all clear about mappings. By using @Onetomany mapping in one entity and @manytoOne mapping at other entities. Using the controller I have to write REST API functions to insert multiple users at a time inside an array or set. Can anyone please suggest some websites or provide some existing codes?

Comment: Do you want to insert bulk records in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

The `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` mappings can be used according to your use-case, whether you need bi-directional mappping or not. For a simple example consider the following :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ENTITY_A")
public class EntityA{

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="EntityA")
    private Set<EntityB> entityBItems;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ENTITY_B")
public class EntityB{

    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="entityA_id", nullable=false)
    private EntityA entityA;

    public EntityB() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

What you need to look out for is the owning side of the relation indicated by the `mappedBy` . The owning entity can be used to persist and get the data from the database. But from the description in your question I cannot understand whether you actually need to use mappings at all as you just have to insert multiple users into a table without any relations to another entity. It will be more helpful if you could explain more about your use case and provide code samples for furthur analysis.

For details about the mappings [article](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/) or [article](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-mapping) .
Official [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) .

Answer (score 0):

MappedBy signals hibernate that the owner of key (relationship) is on the other side.
This means that although you link 2 tables together, only 1 of those tables has a foreign key constraint to the other one.
 `MappedBy` allows you to still link from the table not containing the constraint to the other table.

If you still want use @JoinColumn on both the Entities you can use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` from `com.fasterxml.jackson`

To save the multiple records at same time you can use `yourRepository.saveAll(entities)`